# Corda - Is there any constraint for storing the String data in the corda vault?

Tags: java, h2, corda

I want to store a string data whose size is of 194 characters and above. When I am trying to store such string it is executing flow and state object is getting created, but at the server side it is throwing an exception as follows:

```
 Caused by: net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException:
 com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
 net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence, which is a
 closeable resource, has been detected during flow checkpointing.
 Restoring such resources across node restarts is not supported. Make
 sure code accessing it is confined to a private method or the
 reference is nulled out.
```

I was able to store the String of exact 194 characters without any exception. But if it goes above 200 characters then the exception occurs.

I am using cords 4.3 version and default H2 DB. The String which I am trying to store is:

> "3C03582C57E94C493CEE2B3FFCBAB9757F265DB03EDFB418739D77ECE1C5B66A,EE5B0454A8993279AB1D409872D5B364CD38FCB8C3B6740FB4DEF3B5E55AFEF7,CC96E3E8348ADAC42FFBEA3C7C1A88EDFC7A391421DB6F97FB80C53F52E11F41,69D77466FEACE0F702CBF2244F2A55526DFBC5F1180AB69EA561E15542155AB1"

Answer (score 0):

- The error is not related to String size. Inside your flow, you are using some object that Corda is unable to serialize/deserialize during flow checkpointing/resuming.
  Do you have any object like an HTTP client, or a database connection/result set? If you do, as per the error message; you must set that object reference to `null` once you're done using it.
- To answer your question about String size, the transaction is stored as a Blob of data inside the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table in `TRANSACTION_VALUE` column (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-database-tables.html#transactions)); and I'm pretty sure that Blob column has a really big size (you can check its size using your favorite SQL editor); but you have to keep in mind that what controls the size limitation is actually the `maxTransactionSize` which is one of the network parameters that are set on network level (i.e. all nodes that are part of that network must obey those parameters); so if your `maxTransactionSize` is set to 500 MB, then you can't send a transaction with a size larger than 500 MB even though the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table can handle that (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-map.html#network-parameters)).
  The network parameters are cached inside the `network-parameters` file in the node's directory. You can also view the values of that file using the [node explorer](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-explorer.html).

Comment: I am not facing the size issue for the transaction, I am facing a size issue for one of the declared variables at the schema level. 
Actually the thing is it is getting stored in the state but, not at the schema level.
If I comment that String variable from Schema class (@Column(name = "code")
        private final String code;) then no exception and after running vault query I am able to see the entire string.

Comment: Ok then: 1-Make sure that the column `code` actually exists in the database. 2- If it does exist, check its size. You can set the size of the column with `@Column(name = "code", length = 256)`.